# Can't Change The Content of a Ajax Control After CallBack

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

```
public void RaiseCallbackEvent(String eventArgument)
{
    // Processes a callback event on the server using the event
    // argument from the client.
    //Response.Write(eventArgument);

    printAlternativesFromAirport(eventArgument);
}

    public void printAlternativesFromAirport(string airport)
{
    List<TravelPlan> alternatives = fit.Code.TextDataHelper.GetAllTravelPlansFromCity(airport);

    AlternativesAcc.Panes.Clear();
    AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane p = new AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane();
    Label header = new Label();
    header.Text = airport;
    Label content = new Label();
    content.Text = airport;
    p.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(header);
    p.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(content);
    AlternativesAcc.Panes.Add(p);
```

...

Hi,

printAlternativesFromAirport method should change an accordion panel after the callback but it doesn't. Is there anything that i could set to fix this problem ? There should be stg with the page lifecycle but i can't figure it out !

Thanks